# How to get screen name in Liferay 7 or Liferay DXP

Tags: java, liferay-7

I have the written the below code but its always returning user id (numeric  like '40156' ,'20147' e.t.c) only not user name

Can somebody tell me how to get screen name

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay;
HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) httpRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
            User user = null;
            long userId1 = themeDisplay.getUserId();
            user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserById(userId1);
          String screenname1 = user.getScreenName();
```

Comment: Have you checked that each user has an actual screen name in the persistent store? When users are created and no screen name is specified, do they receive a default value that is essentially their user ID?

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code in java class, i can get the screen name now using the below code

now the "user" object has screen name in the variable _originalScreenName

```
  HttpServletRequest request;
   long companyID = PortalUtil.getCompanyId(request);
   User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(companyID, EmailID);
```